# CJuiDialog Popup not working inside CTabview

Tags: yii

Popup on button click not working,
 popup coding given below,

```
  <?php 
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));

echo 'dialog content here';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

echo CHtml::button("popup",array('title'=>"popup",'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;'));?>
```

Tab implementation coding where the popup file is called,

```
<?php 
$this->widget('CTabView', array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'baseedit_tab'=>array(
            'title'=>'BaseContact Edit Source',
            'view'=>'tab2',
            'data'=>array('model'=>BaseContactEditStructure::model(),),
        ),
        'structure_tab'=>array(
            'title'=>'BaseContact Edit Structure',
           'view'=>'tab2',
            'data'=>array('model'=>BaseContactEditStructure::model()),
        ),
         'import_tab'=>array(
            'title'=>'BaseContactEdit ImportedData',
             'view'=>'BCImportedData',
            'data'=>array('model'=>BaseContactEditStructure::model()),
        ),
         'reflists_tab'=>array(
            'title'=>'RefLists',
            'view'=>'tab2',
            'data'=>array('model'=>BaseContactEditStructure::model()),
        ),
         'documents_tab'=>array(
            'title'=>'Documents',
            'view'=>'tab2',
            'data'=>array('model'=>BaseContactEditStructure::model()),
        ),
       ),

));
?>
```

If 'autoOpen'=>true popup displays but if 'false' popup dialog not opens...